# How to find documentation for Maira DB 10.1?

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to look for documentation for Maria DB 10.1 I cant seem to find it. Each time I go to the Maria DB website it keeps showing me documentation for 10.2.

Anyway I can view the documentation for 10.1? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any 10.2-specific documentation at their site, rather, the docs refer to other versions as applicable to new changes or past versions within their knowledge base info. Do you have an example link to where you are looking?

Answer (score 1):

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/ . There is no version specific documentation, but, for every new feature, there is a mentioning when it was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

It is a single manual, with hints like

```
starting with 10.0.5 ...
```

or

```
MariaDB 10.0.11 introduced ...
```

So, ignore any paragraphs that talk about 10.2 or 10.3.

If you are asking what is new in 10.1 (relative to 10.0), then [*this page*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/changes-improvements-in-mariadb-101/) lists things, with links for more details.